# How to get the max count grouped by a field in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, group-by

Given this table which contains the list of the movies sold by a store :

```
store_id | film_id
---------|--------
1        | 123
1        | 32
2        | 145
1        | 123
2        | 84
2        | 456
1        | 6
2        | 456
```

How can I get the most sold movie by store ( = the most reccurent `film_id` in the table grouped by `store_id`) ? My guess is that would be the `max()` `count(movie_id)` but I can't figure out how to make this work.

I'm trying to get this kind of result :

```
store_id | mostSoldMovieId
---------|--------
1        | 123
2        | 456
```

Comment: If you have had a go at this please show us what you have tried

Comment: And as store 1 didnt sell movie ID 123 at all in your sample code, you may want to check that your example makes sense

Comment: It was indeed an example and I might should have say that the dataset is a subset. Edited for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

If your version of MySql is 8.0+ you can use `RANK()` window function:

```
select t.store_id, t.film_id mostSoldMovieId
from (
  select store_id, film_id,
    rank() over (partition by store_id order by count(*) desc) rn
  from tablename
  group by store_id, film_id
) t
where t.rn = 1
```

This will return ties if 2 films are at the top equally sold for a store.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wQno6rn9ioNtW2vNzZoMYA/2).
For previous versions of MySql you could do this:

```
select 
  t.store_id,
  substring_index(group_concat(t.film_id order by counter desc), ',', 1) film_id
from (
  select store_id, film_id, count(*) counter
  from tablename
  group by store_id, film_id
) t  
group by t.store_id
```

This will not return ties.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wQno6rn9ioNtW2vNzZoMYA/3).
Results:

```
| store_id | film_id |
| -------- | ------- |
| 1        | 123     |
| 2        | 456     |
```

Comment: Thanks for this one. Any example for 5.7 ?